# Folder security vs folder share

Tags: windows-xp, network-shares

This is for Win XP

We got RW permission for a folder (and its sub-folders). When I logon into the PC using previleged ID I am able to read & write. Ex: D:\Folder

But I am not able to write when access I access same folder thru share. Ex: \hostname\d$\folder

What I am missing, what additional previlege I should get?

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at the Share permissions.  By default Everyone only has Read access.  You need to have proper security on both the Share and the Folder permissions.

Comment: yes, I didn't get share permission at all. But I came to know that if I use \\hostname.domain.com\d$\folder, I should get RW permission. That is not the case?

Comment: If you have permissions to access D$ then you should have the ability to write to the folder if you have the permissions properly set.  Can you not write into the root of the folder or into the subfolders?

Comment: When I checked read permission for \\hostname.domain\d$\folder I get "folder doesn't exits"

Comment: If you navigate to just \\systemame\d$ can you read and write there?  Can you see all the folders?

Comment: No, I couldn't. ok Here is my question "for an id thru security permision RW granted. if i want to RW from another box, it should be shared, right?"

Comment: Normally you would create the share, grant Everyone (or that user or a group) RW access to the share, and then grant RW access to the folder.  Using the administrative share (c$ or d$) you would expect to be accessing the share as an administrator, so normally that account has RW access regardless.